# Get all values from a JSON string and delete all duplicates

Tags: php, json

How to get all values of *tags* from [this JSON](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/instagram.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4) string and delete all duplicates?
My code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/instagram.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=myAPIKey',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'cURL Request'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($resp,true);
```

(The API key is a public test key provided by Tumblr)

Comment: Please post a _small representative sample_ of the JSON here, with formatted whitespace. Also, post whitespace formatted output from `print_r($response)` (such as you would see if copied from the browser page source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stab in the dark with the `JSON` decoded `array`:

```
function uniqueTags($jsonArray)
{
    $output = array();
    foreach($jsonArray['response']['posts'] as $post)
    {
        foreach($post['tags'] as $tag)
        {
            //Iterate over tags in all posts returned
            if(!in_array($tag, $output))
            {
                $output[] = $tag;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error from it: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'` Do I miss something?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Now this error comes up: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: Not my code dude!  Upgrade PHP or try something else.

Comment: Woops! Sorry, too used to PHPstorm doing the brackets. Code updated, does it work (even with modification?)

And @AbraCadaver is correct, you have an older PHP version, I'll update it for a lower version.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach($response['response']['posts'] as $posts ){
    if(isset($posts['tags'])){
        foreach($posts['tags'] as $tag){
            echo $tag . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun one:

```
$tags = array_unique(
            call_user_func_array('array_merge', 
                array_column($response['response']['posts'], 'tags')));
```